# Laravel eloquent one to many relationship in custom pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have some tables in a mySQL database and I use laravel to manage access to these tables:

```
-places
   id
   name

-events
   id
   name

-event_place
   id
   event_id
   place_id

-event_dates
   id
   start_date
   end_date
   event_place_id
```

Then I've created the following models in eloquent for above tables:

```
class Place extends Model {

   public function events() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Event', 'event_place', 'place_id', 'event_id')->withPivot('id');
   }

   public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
      if ($parent instanceof Event) {
         return new EventPlace($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
      }
      return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
   }
}

class Event extends Model {

   public function places() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Place', 'event_place', 'event_id', 'place_id')->withPivot('id');
   }

   public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
      if ($parent instanceof Place) {
         return new EventPlace($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
      }
      return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
   }
}

class EventPlace extends Pivot {

   public function event() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Event');
   }

   public function place() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Place');
   }

   public function eventDates() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventDate', 'event_place_id');
   }
}

class EventDate extends Model {

   public function eventPlace() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\EventPlace', 'event_place_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

When I run this code:

```
$dates = App\Models\EventDate::find(1)->eventPlace->toJson();
dump($dates);
```

this error rises:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, none given, called in /Users/hamidzamani/Sites/mycity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 827 and defined
```

anybody can help me?!

Comment: Every time you make a change, you have to exit and re enter Tinker.

Comment: I get the same error !
Did you find a answer or workaround?

Comment: @zeratulmdq comment was the right answer, please convert that to answer for accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you make a change, you have to exit and re enter Tinker.